# swift if statement check string not correctly

Tags: ios, swift

in my iOS app, i have a simple if statement like this:

```
if (responseString! != "No Data")  {
  print("Data available")
}
```

if I print the responseString, this is the result:

> No Data

But the print "Data available" will shown as well.
why?

Comment: How is `responseString` declared?

Comment: let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

Comment: What is the length of `responseString`?

Comment: 27 letters .... i have to be 25

Comment: Have you initialised and declare `responseString`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be whitespaces or newlines in your `responseString`, try this:

```
let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```